# Script to create an ASP.NET Membership provider User

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I created a bunch of insert scripts to add a new user to the aspnet_Membership and aspnet_User table.  I can't auth, says it can't find my user.

Has anyone tried to create a new membership user via T-SQL inserts?  I have to do it this way because our create user code in C#/ASP.NET does not work at the moment.

Answer (score 15):

From MSDN:

```
declare @now datetime
set @now= GETDATE()
exec aspnet_Membership_CreateUser 'MyAppName','admin1','pass@word1', '','admin1@contoso.com','','',1,@now,@now,0,0,null
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252020(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2):

That's most likely because the Membership provider hashes the password (and salts it) for saving and retrieving (the hash is compared, not the unhashed password).

I'm guessing you ran the `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` stored procedure.  That's going to put an unhashed password (and wrong salt).

In other words, you'll need to use the Membership provider/API to create, retrieve, and authenticate.

Comment: NO I just copied an existing password and salt from another user of mine and used it for this new user as well in the insert statement

Comment: "Membership provider/API" yea well that's what's broken in code, and  I don't have time to fix that right now...need to create a user now for a maintenance emergency / test

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Ok, well just do this.  Create an application that has a config file with a connectionString pointing to your database, a membership provider section using that connection string (and your other application name), and roleManager with the same details.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following scripts:

Step 1. User Defined Function to encode password and salt

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[base64_encode] (@data VARBINARY(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) WITH SCHEMABINDING,
                                                                                       RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT BEGIN RETURN
  ( SELECT [text()] = @data
   FOR XML PATH('') ) END GO
```

Step 2. Stored procedure to create membership user

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
  @UserName nvarchar(256)
, @ClearTextPassword nvarchar(128)
, @Email nvarchar(256)
, @pUserId uniqueidentifier


AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @ApplicationName nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @PasswordFormat int
DECLARE @UnencodedSalt uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Password nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @PasswordSalt nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
DECLARE @UniqueEmail int
DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier

SET @ApplicationName = 'ApplicationName' --Find in aspnet_Applications.ApplicationName 
SET @PasswordFormat = 1 
SET @UnencodedSalt = NEWID()
SET @PasswordSalt = dbo.base64_encode(@UnencodedSalt)
SET @Password = dbo.base64_encode(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 
   CAST(@UnencodedSalt as varbinary(MAX)) 
   + CAST(@ClearTextPassword AS varbinary(MAX)) )) 
SET @Now = getutcdate()
SET @UniqueEmail = 1
SET @UserId=@pUserId

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier

EXECUTE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser] 
   @ApplicationName
  ,@UserName
  ,@Password
  ,@PasswordSalt
  ,@Email
  ,NULL
  ,NULL
  ,1 -- IsApproved == true
  ,@Now
  ,@Now
  ,@UniqueEmail
  ,@PasswordFormat
  ,@UserId OUTPUT

COMMIT  

END

GO
```

Step 3. Create the user

```
DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier

SET @UserId = NewId()

EXECUTE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
           'UserName'   --@UserName
          ,'UserP@ssword '--@ClearTextPassword
          ,'user@email.com '--@Email
          ,@UserId --User's uniqueidentifier
```

Additional Notes:

1. Check your application name is correct in your web.config membership element.
2. Remember create roles and add user to roles.

Comment: where do i get [aspnet_Membership_CreateUser]  or did my sql server admin lock me out ... ?

Comment: Same problem here. You won't have the aspnet_Membership_CreateUser command if you let visual studio set up the membership provider tables.